# How to convert postman collection V1 to V2 in link format

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have some collection postman v1 but are in link format, is there any way to transform to .json files so i can use the postman collection converter?

Comment: Install an old version of Postman (https://go.pstmn.io/dl-win64-v7-latest), import it there and then export it as v2.